# Kubernetes Client gives Forebidden error when tried to read the ingress list body

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, permission-denied

I am trying to update/remove a K8S Ingress rule dynamically using the Kubernetes Client. The code below helps to get the ingress object based on its name and then update the ingress rules using Ingress Spec.

```
var listIngress = client.ListNamespacedIngressWithHttpMessagesAsync("MyIngress");
var objIngress = listIngress.Result.Body.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata.Name == "MyIngress");
var patchSpec = objIngress.Spec;
```

A clusterrole is defined with verbs for resources as given below and assigned to the required user.

--verb create,update,patch,delete,get,list,watch,deletecollection
--resource services,deployments,ingresses,ingressclasses,endpoints,pods

This works fine with the ealier versions of kubernetes but with the latest versions 1.22.0, it gives below error when tried to get the listIngress.Result.Body.Items. But there are no errors reported with any of the other resources but only with Ingress.

```
 {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "error": "One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden')"
}
```

Please help me to understand and resolve this problem.

Comment: See if you can log the network traffic to find out what requests are being sent. With kubectl you can use --v=9 (i.e. very verbose). Alternatively you could use a man-in-the-middle such as https://mitmproxy.org, but start with the logging facilities in the API you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It was really helpful. I had to  redefine the APIs a bit to work in k8s v22, the kube apis doesnt have body attribute listIngress.Result.Body.Items.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question with the details? That might help others.